# Find function in vector and the keys of a map

Tags: c++

The Vector find function can search an inserted value even if you try and find by providing substring . Is this same in case of the keys of a map ?

```
   int main()
   { 
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("text");
    v.push_back("[[text");
    v.push_back("text");

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
     {
       if (v[i].find("[[") == 0)
       {
         v[i].append("]]");
       }
     }
  }
```

Here it finds "[[text" and makes it "[[text]]" .

I tried it in map but code crashes on run time ,. I am using Dev c++

```
   int main()
{
      std::multimap<string, string> m;
      std::multimap<string, string> intersection;
      std::multimap<string, string>::iterator it8;

      m.insert(pair< string, string>("4-2"," 61-7" ));
      m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-2"," 61-7" ));

     multimap<string, string>::iterator it4;
     multimap<string, string>::iterator it5;
    for ( it4 = m.begin(); it4 !=m.end(); it4++)
    {
        if (m.find("5-") == 0)
        it5=it4;      
    }
    cout << " result of 5 search is" << (*it5).first << ", " << (*it5).second <<endl;
    m.clear();
   getchar();

 }
```

Comment: You are never using any "vector find function", and indeed no such function exists.

Comment: @KerrekSB ok so this is a Strung find function or something else but if you try and do it in map which has a key and value as string it wont fetch you find result for partial string over here as "[[" has been passed . BUT will this find work in case of set where we have just key and not key value concept as Map ?

Comment: See Wilx's answer: sets and maps have immutable keys, so you can only get a `const string &` to them. `find` still works, but `append` doesn't.

Comment: Looking at the second block of code in the question, I don't think @Ritesh wants to modify the keys, but just find the keys which *contain* the substring "5-". That's the assumption I made in my answer, anyway. Ritesh, is this your goal? If not, what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sample correct code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/maOMd))

The error is that this line

```
if (m.find("5-") == 0)
```

will never succeed. You maybe be surprised at this. `m.find("5-")` searches through the entire map looking for an entry whose key is *exactly* equal to "5-". Your keys are "4-2" and "5-2".

Do you wish to find *keys* which *contain* the substring "5-"? Then you need something like

```
it4->first.find("5-"); // check if the key string at this entry contains "5-"
```

I think you want a loop like this:

```
multimap<string, string>::iterator it4;
for ( it4 = m.begin(); it4 !=m.end(); it4++)
{
    if (it4->first.find("5-") != string :: pos)
            cout << " result of 5 search is" << it4->first << ", " << it4->second <<endl;      
}
```

As others have pointed out, you are *not* interested in the the `find` method of `vector` or `map`. You are interested in the find method of `string` - this is quite different. The title of your question is a little misleading as a result (unintentionally).

Comment: Thanks for the lovely explaination .It was a big blunder on my part how i missed iterator and started searching in map without it..Regards

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `std::set<>` is that you cannot modify its elements in place because you could violate the ordering it has. You can however iterate from `set.begin()` to `set.end()` using iterators (instead of `operator[]`) and remove and reinsert modified elements.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . But in case i pass a partial string of my element will it be able to find it in set as in case of vector . I can then in that case store that iterator and erase it or whatever operation i want to do with that

Comment: something like this

for ( it4 = m.begin(); it4 !=m.end(); it4++)
        {
            if (m.find("5 ") == 0)
            it5=it4;      
        }